# get category image

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category

I am trying to fetch category images next to product title. Problem is that below code works weird. I am able to get url of image, but sometimes url is not reachable therefore img will not show up. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php        
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
$_category  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId);
$image= $_category->getImageUrl();

echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" height="40" width="40">';

?>
```